# mysql 5.5.9 -- install in windows

Tags: mysql

I just downloaded zipped-up version of mysql 5.5.9 (mysql-5.5.9.zip, which I put in c:\progream files), unzipped it, and got this dir (screenshot):
http://mayacove.com/misc/ss_mysql.gif

I hadn't installed mysql server on windows in a few years.. I remember that years ago you used to get an installer called setup.exe, when you ran that it ran instal/config wizard, that would walk you thru installation and setup.. so how do I run that wizard now???

no file with ext .exe inside this dir (no file with ext .msi either) no serious instructions here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installation-layout.html

would appreciate some help.. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

You should use msi installer. [It's on download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) first or second option.

Comment: ok, finally!!! found this TREASURE!!! http://timlin.net/csm/cis363/mysql.pdf which wawlked me through every step (some things I remembered, but not all..)  was just able to connect to mysql on the shell :-)  (tonight at home have to install on MAC OSx.. yikes.. have never installed on MAC..) thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

There is a package available with a MSI installer.

Just follow the instructions on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: thank you for yr response.. am downloading msi installer (so .zip no good? where is it there then?) but I don't see instructions here.. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ or here